# React Native and using websockets

Tags: react-native

I have such code with react-native@0.17

```
import React, { AsyncStorage, Component, View, Text, WebView, WebSocket } from 'react-native';
import { Avatar, Divider, Subheader, COLOR } from 'react-native-material-design';

export default class Avatars extends Component {
    _setWebSocket = (endpoint, sessionToken) => {
      const ws = new WebSocket('wss://' + endPoint + '/api/live?authToken=' + sessionToken);
      console.log('Setting socket: ' + 'wss://' + endpoint + '/api/live?authToken=' + sessionToken);
```

and I'm calling code from:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this._setWebSocket(endpoint, token);
 }
```

I have issue with trying to get WebSockets to be working as code:

```
console.log('Setting socket: ' + 'wss://' + endpoint + '/api/live?authToken=' + sessionToken);
```

never is triggered . If I put console log before creating new WebSocket it runs. What I'm doing wrong and how can I debug as chrome isn't showing useful information in combination with Genymotion.

Comment: Do you use "Debug JS remotely" from the context menu in Genymotion? If not, type `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` in your console to see logs

Comment: My code successfully instanciate a WebSocket but trigger its `onerror` handler for an unknown reason :/

Comment: Ended up using socket.io and it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue was easy to find and probably I was tired

```
import React, { AsyncStorage, Component, View, Text, WebView, WebSocket } from 'react-native';
```

I put WebSocket to be imported but this is native module ...
So removing WebSocket from import dependencies helped.

Comment: In case anyone else is as stuck on this as I was, remove the `WebSocket` import completely. It's a global and doesn't need to be imported at all. @Marceli could you remove this line of code from this answer? It's a little misleading. Thanks!

Comment: @LaneRettig +1 agree